# the program stop run is caused by python udp stay in a place

Tags: python, sockets, centos, udp

I have one question about `socket` in python.
I use `udp-protocol` in my program. There is the following error usually happening in the program. My program stay in a point. Using `pstack pid`, the detail message is as follows：

```
$ pstack 12776
#0  0x000000318b20e9a3 in __recvfrom_nocancel () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f2fbc14fad1 in sock_recvfrom_guts () from /home/work/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
#2  0x00007f2fbc14fd82 in sock_recvfrom () from /home/work/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
#3  0x000000000049bdc0 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#4  0x000000000049c83e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#5  0x000000000049c83e in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#6  0x000000000049d93e in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#7  0x000000000049da52 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#8  0x00000000004bd2f0 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#9  0x00000000004bd4bc in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#10 0x000000000041608c in Py_Main ()
#11 0x000000318ae1ecdd in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#12 0x0000000000415019 in _start ()
```

I think `upd-protocol` should be no problem. I really don't understand why the condition happens. There is no one can help me, thank you！The python's version is 2.7.3.My code follows:

```
address = (server_ip, server_port);
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(send_buf, address)
response, addr = s.recvfrom(2048)
if response:
    real_body = self.parse_response(response)
```

Comment: Sounds like your thread is waiting to receive data and waits for it until forever. Do you have any code for us?

Comment: @TinyT  
My code follows:

address = (server_ip, server_port);
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(send_buf, address)
response, addr = s.recvfrom(2048)
if response:
    pass

Comment: could you please add the code to your question (instead of a comment), preferrably indented (with blank lines above and below) to format it? Especially with Python it's a bit harsh not to have any indentation or line feed. Also: are you sure your socket is receiving a response?

Comment: @TinyTI have added code.

Comment: Are you sure the server *is* sending a response? Do you have access to what it does?

Comment: @TinyTI have solved the problem. My server send data only once,but client maybe dont't receive data.So it wait for .... Thank you TinyT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason.I used udp protocol in my code.Sometimes because of net problem, client can't data that server send.
Final, I solved this problem by using select function in client.